# Handling special character values while fetching the data from the database and displaying in textarea pageitem- APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

When I try to set the value in the textarea item by using plsql function body in dynamic action, for example I fetch data 'Update' from database for textarea , it gets displayed as &# x27;UPDATE&# x27; also '&requester' as &# x27;& amp;requester&# x27;

what must be done to handle it?
PS:The space in &# x27; in intentional as it was automatically getting converted to '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is that item's "Escape special characters" property set to? If it is "No", then set it to "Yes".

---

Or, while fetching data from the database, now you have e.g.

```
select some_column from your_table
```

Switch to

```
select utl_i18n.unescape_reference(some_column) from your_table
```